# NodeJS request inside function, not able to get variable

Tags: node.js, variables, get, request

I have the function bellow:

```
function scrape( id, url ){
        request.get(url, function(err, resp, data) {
                // I need to use the variable ID here
        });
}
```

I need to use the variable id inside the request.get but I can't find a way to do it.

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: variable `id` IS available inside request what's your error/issue?

Comment: my issue is that it isn't, it returns me "undefined" when I console.log inside the request and returns me the proper id when I do it outside, either before or after the request

Comment: Then you need to post more code. If id is undefined inside the request callback, it is also undefined inside the `scrape` function. Unless you change it inside `scrape`.

Comment: building on what you both said, @EduardoLeoni -- try moving the `console.log` to just after the opening bracket for the scrape function.  I'll bet that `id` isn't defined anyplace in the function...it's not a problem with `request`.

Comment: you lads are right, I messed up.
Found the issue, thanks